# Problem to view the content of my listview

Tags: java, android, mysql, xml, sqlite

edit and delete item in a listview but the problem is that the app crash when i want to see my list

I already saw that the problem is at the line 34 because the value of "user" is null

```
public class PageUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<User> userList;
    ListView listView;
    User user;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page_user);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getListContents();
        int numRows = data.getCount();
        if (numRows == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(PageUser.this, "Aucun utilisateur enregistré !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                user = new User( data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3)); //The problem is here
                userList.add(i, user);
                System.out.println(data.getString(1) + " " + data.getString(2) + " " + data.getString(3));
                i++;
            }
            UserAdaptater adapter = new UserAdaptater(this, R.layout.user_cell, userList);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.maListe);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String recupID = userList.get(i).getID();
                    String recupNom = userList.get(i).getNom();
                    String recupPrenom = userList.get(i).getPrenom();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PageUser.this, EditUser.class);
                    intent.putExtra("ID",recupID);
                    intent.putExtra("name",recupNom);
                    intent.putExtra("fname",recupPrenom);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void page_ajouter(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AddUser.class));
    }
}
```

this is the user class

package com.example.changepage;

```
public class User {

private String ID;
private String nom;
private String prenom;

public User(String id, String nom, String prenom) {
    this.ID = id;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}
}
```

and my getListContents function

```
public Cursor getListContents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}
```

[debug PageUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KXmO.png)

I want to fix this problem to see the list

Comment: This could be a number of things.  Please add the debug.  What does the getListContents() function return and what does the User class look like?

Comment: Ok so the getListContents() function return the data and I added the debug. Thx for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating separate variables and assigning the cursor data to these first and then create the User with these.  You can call add with new User().

Also be aware that your first index (for _id) is 1! Is this correct? It may start at 0.  This is why i was asking what the getListContents() function returns; as in, what the data structure looks like.

```
String _id = "";
String _nom = "";
String _prenom = "";

while (data.moveToNext()) {
    _id = data.getString(1);
    _nom = data.getString(2);
    _prenom = data.getString(3);

    if(_id == null || _nom == null || _prenom == null) {
        System.out.println("Database field is null!");
    }
    else {
        userList.add( new User( _id, _nom, _prenom));
        System.out.println(_id  + " " + _nom  + " " + _prenom);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me my error was that the data.getString() started by 1 and not 0

Comment: Glad i could help